# android 8:SELinux: Could not open /sepolicy: No such file or directory

Tags: android

i am booting the boot image for android 8. but it gets stuck at this stage.
[During init first stage it is not finding the selinux policy files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GluvW.png)

Comment: I don't think this is the right place for these type of question , you might find help on https://android.stackexchange.com/