# Android Emulator (AVD) fails to boot in MacOS

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, selinux

My android emulator fails to boot when the target platform is Level 26 (Android 8.0.0) or higher. The emulator just shows a black screen while the emulator process is constantly running at approx. 100% CPU. Note that level 25 and lower work fine.

Here's what I discovered so far:

I launched the emulator from the command-line so that I can inspect the logcat:

```
./emulator -avd Test2 -logcat '*:e'
```

Here's an excerpt from the logcat:

```
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.18.91+ (android-build@wphr1.hot.corp.google.com) (gcc version 4.9 20140827 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jan 9 20:30:51 UTC 2018
[    0.000000] Command line: qemu=1 androidboot.hardware=ranchu clocksource=pit androidboot.console=ttyS0 android.qemud=1 console=0 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1 androidboot.logcat=*:e androidboot.selinux=permissive ndns=2 ndns=2
[    0.000000] Disabled fast string operations
... 
(skipping a few hundred lines)
...
[    1.443608] init: init first stage started!
[    1.443608] init: Using Android DT directory /proc/device-tree/firmware/android/
[    1.443608] init: First stage mount skipped (missing/incompatible fstab in device tree)
[    1.453842] init: Skipped setting INIT_AVB_VERSION (not in recovery mode)
[    1.453842] init: Loading SELinux policy
[    1.453842] selinux: SELinux:  Could not open /sepolicy:  No such file or directory
[    1.453842] 
[    1.463161] init: Failed to load monolithic SELinux policy: No such file or directory
[    1.463161] init: panic: rebooting to bootloader
[    1.463161] init: Reboot start, reason: reboot, rebootTarget: bootloader
[    1.472277] init: android::WriteStringToFile open failed: No such file or directory
[    1.472277] init: Shutdown timeout: 6
[    1.472277] init: terminating init services
[    1.472277] init: waitpid failed: No child processes
[    1.482231] init: Terminating running services took 0.013438 seconds with remaining services:0
[    1.482231] init: waitpid failed: No child processes
[    1.482231] init: vold not running, skipping vold shutdown
[    1.607664] init: powerctl_shutdown_time_ms:128:0
[    1.607664] init: Reboot ending, jumping to kernel
[    1.607664] reboot: Restarting system with command 'bootloader'
[    1.607664] reboot: machine restart
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.18.91+ (android-build@wphr1.hot.corp.google.com) (gcc version 4.9 20140827 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jan 9 20:30:51 UTC 2018
[    0.000000] Command line: qemu=1 androidboot.hardware=ranchu clocksource=pit androidboot.console=ttyS0 android.qemud=1 console=0 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1 androidboot.logcat=*:e androidboot.selinux=permissive ndns=2 ndns=2
[    0.000000] Disabled fast string operations
...
```

This repeats infinitely every 5 seconds. So I suspect my problem has something to do with SELinux. That would make sense, since Android 8 introduced many changes in that area: https://source.android.com/security/selinux/

But I have no clue why others don't have this problem nor what to do about it.

Comment: What is your AVD config?

Comment: Also, have you tried creating a new AVD from scratch?

Comment: I think others are having this problem, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51761579/android-8selinux-could-not-open-sepolicy-no-such-file-or-directory) and it might be something with `/sepolicy`?

Comment: Tried several AVD configs, and changing just android version makes the difference. But here's one: Device: Nexus One, Target: Android 8.0.0 - API Level 26, CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86_64), Keyboard: no, Skin: Skin with dynamic hardware controls, Cameras: none, RAM: 512, Heap: 32, Storage: 200MB, Emulation: Use Host GPU

Comment: It can be caused by the Linux driver of your graphics. Have you tried use Software Graphic (virtual device settings → Emulated Performance)?

Comment: Hi Francis, I'm on MacOS. And I tried with and without "use host GPU" to no avail.

Comment: Just a guess, but I think it might have to do with the filesystem error you're getting _prior_ to the `/sepolicy` one (`missing/incompatible fstab in device tree`).  This could explain why it can't find the `/sepolicy` file.  Also, I found [this site](http://selinuxproject.org/page/NB_SEforAndroid_1#SELinux_Policy_Files) helpful re `/sepolicy`.  Unfortunately, I don't know why moving to level 26 would cause this.  Do you get that same message in the level <=25 logs too?

Comment: Ah ha.  Now I think I understand why it changed at level 26 (Android 8.0) after skimming [this](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/kernel/modular-kernels) (in particular, the "Mounting Partitions Early" section).

Comment: Device: Nexus One, Target: Android 8.0.0 - API Level 26, CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86_64), Keyboard: no, Skin: Skin with dynamic hardware controls, Cameras: none, RAM: 512, Heap: 32, Storage: 200MB, Emulation: Use Host GPU : For this Configuration make sure, Google APIs Intel Atom (x86_64) image installed for API 26.0 and RAM should be 1GB And Above and min Storage should be 512 MB.

Comment: You might try disabling SELinux, as well as looking at the kernel startup messages, like:  `./emulator -avd Test2 -logcat '*:e' -selinux disabled -show-kernel`

Comment: @KrisVanBael I have exactly the same problem but on Windows 7 using eclipse. Have you fond the solution? I see that none of the answers is accepted.

Comment: @viktor. No solution. In the end I had to go buy an android 8 device to get my software tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered it was an SELinux issue on the host.  This is one way to resolve it:

```
sudo setsebool -P selinuxuser_execheap 1
```

There are more specific ways, too.  But, you'll want to catch the exception to get the exact command:

Allow this access for now by executing:

```
ausearch -c 'qemu-system-x86' --raw | audit2allow -M my-qemusystemx86
semodule -X 300 -i my-qemusystemx86.pp
```

Of course, you can test in general by making SELinux temporarily permissive on your host.

After I did that, the phone display was no longer black.

Comment: In the meantime I ported my project to AndroidStudio and did a clean install on all SDK's folders. Since I'm not able to check your answer, you get the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wiping data of **emulator** from **AVD wizard**?

I had same issue and got it solved by wiping emulator before launch.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue may most probably related to the GPU driver. **Try to install the proper GPU driver.**

It is hard to find for some GPUs.  If you couldn't find one, force using software graphics as described below.

Go to virtual device settings and then `Software` as graphics under emulated performance section. This may significantly slow down the performance. However it will work without issues.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select **"Software"** in the **"Emulated Performance Graphics"** option, in the AVD settings instead of "Automatic" or "Hardware"

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution.
Delete android folder.
Reinstall android sdk .
Delete the avd setting inside user Folders.
create new AVD.

Comment: I tried it, but it still didn't work. I am getting more and more convinced that it is plain impossible to develop for Android 9 on Eclipse. In the meantime Google even took the eclipse downloads offline.

Comment: try running as admin through terminal or command prompt.It takes time for first time.